# ardrone_ brown ardrone error in camera

Tags: ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi!

i would like to use ardrone_brown on my ArDrone 2.0. but i have a error.
when i use this package with this tutorial " [http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/wiki/index.php/Controlling_the_ARDRONE_with_the_Brown-ROS_package"](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/wiki/index.php/Controlling_the_ARDRONE_with_the_Brown-ROS_package%22)

I can take off/ land and Move my ArDrone but I have problem with the camera.

I type

$ roscore
$rosrun ardrone_brown ardrone_driver
$rosrun drone_teleop drone_teleop.py

but when I type :

"  rosrun image_view image_view image:=/ardrone/image_raw "
in my terminal, i can not watch the signal of my Ardrone Camera.

P.S. I use UBUNTU 12.01 and ROS FUERTE

P.S.2 It is not a error in my camera because i also try to use the drive Ardrone _ autonomy and i can watch  my camera but i want to use the other driver because i want to use for navigation on vision.

Sorry for my english.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46691/ardrone_-brown-ardrone-error-in-camera/) by [juanproject](https://answers.ros.org/users/3459/juanproject/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ardrone_brown is now deprecated.  I have been using the ardrone_autonomy fork, and it seems to work well.

I also recommend using mjpeg_server to view images through browsers.

---

Originally posted by [odestcj](https://answers.ros.org/users/313/odestcj/) with karma: 123 on 2012-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2